# Account-specific bookmarks in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is it possible to have only my work-related bookmarks show up when I log in to my work Chrome account and only my personal bookmarks show up when I am logged in to my personal Chrome account?  Now they all show up in both accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just [add new users to Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824):

1. Click the Chrome menu [image: Chrome menu] on the browser toolbar and select **Settings**.
2. In the **Users** section, click **Add new user**.
3. A confirmation dialog appears, choose a picture and enter a name for the new Chrome user.
4. Click **Create**.
5. A new window for the user appears, with a picture you've chosen for the user in the top corner. Here, you can sign in to Chrome with a Google Account to associate the account with the user. Once signed in, all the bookmarks, apps, extensions, theme, and browser settings for the user will be synced to the account.

Do the above twice to create users named **Home** and **Work**, and associate them with the corresponding personal and work-related Google Accounts.

To switch users, just click the icon on the top corner of the Chrome window or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to select the user. No icon will appear if you only have one user associated with the browser.

Note: If you do the above and still find each user displaying the bookmarks of the other, you may have synced back online from the PC a mixture of bookmarks from both accounts. In this case once you have two separate users set up in Chrome and associated with two separate Google Accounts, you should be able to switch to User 1 and delete User 2's bookmarks, then switch to User 2 and delete User 1's bookmarks. Henceforth the two accounts' bookmarks should stay separate due to the separation of users in the browser.